# Fluent NHibernate with Castle Facility Naming Strategy

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, castle-windsor

I have Fluent NHiberate with the Castle Facility up and running.

However, how do you set the NamingStrategy? I tried with the Configuration object, with no luck. Does my naming strategy need to be registered in my Windsor container?

Comment: how about http://fluentnhibernate.org/api/FluentNHibernate.Mapping/PropertyMap.htm#Access ?

Comment: I'd rather first use the Naming Strategy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can tell, there is no way to configure a naming strategy in the NHibernate facility. Please [create a new issue](http://support.castleproject.org/projects/FACILITIES/issuesbrowser) about this.

As a workaround, you can inherit from the [`DefaultConfigurationBuilder`](http://svn.castleproject.org:8080/svn/castle/trunk/Facilities/NHibernateIntegration/Castle.Facilities.NHibernateIntegration/Builders/DefaultConfigurationBuilder.cs) and override `GetConfiguration()` where you would apply your NamingStrategy.

To use this new `IConfigurationBuilder` you just created, inject it to the `NHibernateFacility` when creating it:

```
container.AddFacility(new NHibernateFacility(new MyNamingStrategyConfigurationBuilder()));
```

Of course, the best solution would be that you implement this in the DefaultConfigurationBuilder and submit a patch ;-)

Comment: What about Configuration.SetNamingStrategy(...)?

Comment: Of course, Configuration.SetNamingStrategy() is what you have to call inside the overriden GetConfiguration(). AFAIK SetNamingStrategy() has to be called before any mappings are registered, so it has to be there.